# Open Chrome Settings Tab by clicking a link in a different browser

Tags: google-chrome, settings

I am currently writing an install guide for an application which requires Google Chrome. I am writing the install guide with HTML and what I would like to be able to do, once they have installed Google Chrome, is to launch the Google Chrome Settings tab from whichever browser they are current using.

I have already tried just doing it from an anchor tag (which obviosuly doesn't work) such as:

```
<a href="chrome://chrome/settings/">Open Chrome Settings</a>
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to do something like this or should I just tell them to open Chrome from the start menu and click on the wrench/list/whatever their settings icon is now days?

Comment: I re-asked on superuser and got 1 answer. In short, no it is not possible without third party tools. http://superuser.com/questions/509501/open-chrome-settings-tab-by-clicking-a-link-in-a-different-browser